# Redmine: Cannot enable Git repo command

Tags: redmine

I have installed Redmine in linux OS. And also git.
when I wanna enable git version control in [Settings->Repositories] tab page, it always shows red error icon. But actually I can use git command with Redmine user.
Please help. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, Redmine searches for the `git` command in the `$PATH` environment variable set in the running application server process. Depending on how exactly you start your Redmine, this environment variable might not contain the directory containing the `git` executable.

Luckily, you can tell Redmine exactly where to find the git executable without having to use the `$PATH`. For that, please edit your `config/configuration.yml` file (if it does not exist, you can copy a template over from `config/configuration.yml.example`). There, you can set the full path to your git executable on the `scm_git_command` key.